# Translating "No comments" blog post

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I did setup multi-site and I am trying to translate "No comments" to Arabic language but it does not work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

in directory of public_html/wp-content/themes/your_theme/

you’ll find your "comments.php" file you can customize.

[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/8Y__XArtWq1Y)

Comment: Please share the code as text instead of image.